# On Form submission html page is directed to another page - How to prevent that

Tags: javascript, php, email-validation

I have below html and java script but on form submission the page is directed to mail.php  and not staying on index.html - Any help please.

Secondly i would like to show the message on the form at the bottom of the form the success message that email is sent.

I have debugged the java script and it by passes the if condition as well.

```
<form method="post" name="FrmEnquiry" id="FrmEnquiry" action="mail.php" onsubmit="sendEnquiryform();">
    <input name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">

    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="20" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <div class="submit">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
<span id="sucessMessage"> </span>
```

Mail.Php

```
function sendEnquiryform() {
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var message = $('#message').val();
$.post('mail.php', '&name=' + name + '&email=' + email + message, function(
    result,
    status,
    xhr
) {
    if (status.toLowerCase() == 'error'.toLowerCase()) {
        alert('An Error Occurred..');
    } else {
        //alert(result);
        $('#sucessMessage').html(result);
    }
}).fail(function() {
    alert('something went wrong. Please try again');
});
```

}

Comment: Remove the action attribute from the Form tag

Comment: It always skip the 'if' condition in java script any idea why, as i have been debugging it. @WardNsour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the default form submission behavior, return `false` from your `submit` event handler.

Change your `onsubmit` attribute to

```
<form method="post" name="FrmEnquiry" id="FrmEnquiry"
 action="mail.php" onsubmit="return sendEnquiryform();">
```

and then return `false` from the event handler.

```
function sendEnquiryform() {
    // ...
    return false;
}
```

Since you're making an Ajax call, the `action` attribute becomes unnecessary and can be removed.

---

Change your `fail()` callback function as

```
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert('something went wrong. Please try again');
});
```

and check your browser console log <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for the underlying error message.

Comment: On the function in java script it always skip this function as i would like to show the success message on the form  @ravi       
   function(
            result,
            status,
            xhr
        ) {
            if (status.toLowerCase() == 'error'.toLowerCase()) {
                alert('An Error Occurred..');
            } else {
                //alert(result);
                $('#sucessMessage').html(result);
            }

Comment: @kohatian Answer updated. Please change your error handling code to see what the underlying error message is.

Comment: k : i get 405 method not allowed in console..fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);

        alert('something went wrong. Please try again');
    });

Comment: @kohatian 405 error indicates that either your web server does not support *post* requests or, if you are using a php framework, some configuration issue in your routes file that would probably be better solved by posting a new question.

Comment: Thanks it did indeed

Comment: @kohatian If you post a new question regarding your 405 error, tag me here and I'll try to help you with that as well. Thanks.